# jQuery Modal Form Validation not working when saving with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, dialog

I'm hoping one of the experts here can point me in the right direction with a jQuery dialog script I have been working on..

My problem:  I can't get validation to work with my dialog window when saving via $.ajax().  My script works just fine if I don't save via AJAX and just submit the form:

eg. $( this ).find('form#mws-validate-event').submit();

If anyone has some time to look over the code that I have left below and help with the validation part I would really appreciate it. I have searched high and low on stackoverflow but have yet to find the solution.

thanks.

```
        $("#mws-addform-dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false, 
                title: "My Form / Add New", 
                modal: true, 
                width: "480",
            //working validation (NO AJAX)
            //buttons: [{
            //      text: "Submit", 
            //      click: function() {
            //          $( this ).find('form#mws-validate-event').submit();
            //      }}] 
            buttons: {
            "Submit": function() {

            },
            'Save': function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'ajax.php?action=addnew',
                    data : $('#mws-validate-event').serialize(),
                    beforeSubmit : function (){
                        // Validate data before submit?? anyone??
                        //$( this ).find('form#mws-validate-event').submit();
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        // Show OK message
                        $('#mws-validate-event').find('.mws-form-message').html(data);
                        alert('ok');
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        // Show error message
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });

            },
            'Cancel': function() {

                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
          } 
        });

        $("#mws-addform-dialog-btn").bind("click", function(event) {
            $("#mws-addform-dialog").dialog("option", {modal: true}).dialog("open");
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        //- modal form

        // validate form        
        $("#mws-validate-event").validate({
        //ignore: ".ignore",
            rules: {
                spinner: {
                    required: true, 
                    max: 5
                }

            }, 
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                    var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                    $("#mws-validate-error").html(message).show();
                } else {
                    $("#mws-validate-error").hide();
                    }
            }
        });
        //- validate form
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried validating with jquery validator?  It does most of the validation work for you and is easy to use.

```
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
```